# Share Image Not working Android 6.0

Tags: java, android

I have one android application which have share image function as well save image. This functions are working fine in other than android 6.0 . When I try to share image with whatsapp as well other application, image does not getting attached. My java code for share image like below. What Should I correct for solve the issue ?
Thanks Friends for support :)

```js
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
         
            try {

                myFileUrl = new URL(args[0]);
                //myFileUrl1 = args[0];

                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                String path = myFileUrl.getPath();
                String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Hindi Picture/");
                dir.mkdirs();
                String fileName = idStr;
                file = new File(dir, fileName);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bmImg.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fos);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath()));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
            pDialog.dismiss();
            
            
                }
            });
            
        }
```

Comment: Whats your targetSdk?

Comment: Hi @Nisarg  its 23. Thanks

Comment: You need to handle runtime permission manually for marshmallow devices. please go through [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)